# How to use req.body via get request in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, get, ejs

I have a form which uses a GET method. i also have an input with the name 'a'.
when i handle the request on the server side (nodejs) i want to be able to use req.body.a  (in order to search 'a' in the db).
the problem is that the 'req.body' only seems to work with a POST method.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `GET` method then the data is sent as query parameters

```
req.query
```

By the way there will be no body for `GET` method. If you want to send data through body use `POST` or `PUT` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can access `req.body` in `GET` method just as you would in a `POST` method. Here's an example:

```
export const getFile = (req, res) => {
  const { fileId } = req.body; 

  console.log(fileId)
}
```

Although you CAN do this, I would suggest avoiding it because it goes against HTTP conventions. Instead, put whatever data you want in the URL parameters, which you can access in Node.JS using `req.params`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is if you have to send a body via the get request , it is

1. Send the body through params - `http://--your-api-url/:body` and then retrieve them via `const {body}=req.params` and you can send multiple params through it and retrieve it by the same way .

2.Use Post request,and then it retrieve it through the `req.body`, and then return your data which is expected from the database, it serves the same way though.

3.It is not suggested to use http `GET` while  you send a `req.body` as it violates the http protocol best practice also when you use `axios` for network calls then you wont be able to send the data as `second parameter` to the function as it expects `Authorization Bearer` as the second params.