# I tried using body-parser but it seems like it is not working

Tags: javascript, express, body-parser

Im using body parser with express but is not working and it is returning empty object when i print  req.body in the console.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/' ,function(req,res){
var name = "ganesh"
console.log(req.body.name);
res.render('home',{name : name});
});

app.post('/postname' , function(req,res){
res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("server started");
};
```

this is my home.ejs file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>practice</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        hello<%= name %> This is the home page
    </h1>
    <form action="/postname" method = "POST">
        <input type = "text" name="name">
        <button>
            go
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

i have correctly installed body-parser ejs and express

this is printed in the console:

server started
   {}

Comment: I believe `redirect` tells the *client* to make a redirect (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect). I.e. the client makes a POST request with the data to your server. The server tells the client "make a GET request to / instead". The client makes a GET request without data to /.  Why don't you put `console.log(req.body.name);` in the `/postname` route, because that's where your data is sent to, and make sure that this works? Then you can figure out how to handle the redirect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248770/7026966

Comment: Yea I got it thankyou so much☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the `postname` request to `/`, Please note that this will not forward `request data` to `/` root route.

The `res.redirect("/")` will send a response back to client with `302` status, and then the client will make a `Get` request to `/` route without any data. hence the `request.body` will always has empty data in `Get` request.

You could handle the data in `postname` route and then redirect it.

If you want to forward the data from `postname` to `/` route then you could pass it in the `query string`.

**Example:**

```
var app = express();
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var name = "ganesh"
    res.render('home', { name: req.query.name });
});
app.post('/postname', function (req, res) {
    var name = "ganesh"
    console.log(req.body.name);
    // handle the post data here 
    res.redirect("/?name=" + req.body.name);
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server started");
});
```

Comment: So does the req.query.name have the value of what is passed in the /?name = + req.body.name which is then passed into home.ejs file???

Comment: yes , it will pass this value as query string and then you can retrieve it in root route

Comment: Yea sure....thankyou so much....I will let you know if it worked once I try after some time...☺